# How to use magit-list-repositories?

Tags: magit

I have set `magit-repositories-directory` like this:

```el
(setq magit-repository-directories
      `("~/go/src/github.com/cescoferraro" ,user-emacs-directory))
```

Then I can `M-x magit-list-repositories RET` and I get a nice list containing all Git projects inside that folder.

### Issue 1

I get `Name`, `Version`, `L<U`, `U>L` and `Path` columns.

But what does `L<U`, `U>L` mean? I get 0 values for only random repos. I could not figure out what it means. Ideally I want to know if there is something modified that needs to be pushed and if there is something at `origin` that needs to be pulled.

### Issue 2

I want to use this as a sync tool. So I want to be able to push/pull and open `magit-status` for each project as I browse the list.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Note

`L` for "local branch" has since been renamed to `B` for "branch": https://github.com/magit/magit/commit/cfb2b57bfb0e7ac8ded90bc57c4952612c1edd4b

#### Issue 1

- `B<U` is calculated by the function `magit-repolist-column-unpulled-from-upstream`, which inserts the number of upstream commits not in the current branch.
- `B>U` is calculated by the function `magit-repolist-column-unpushed-to-upstream`, which inserts the number of commits in the current branch but not its upstream.

In other words, a nonzero value in either column means the local branch and its upstream are out of sync.  You can sort the `*Magit Repositories*` buffer (and other tabulated lists in Emacs) by placing point in the desired column and invoking `M-x tabulated-list-sort` (default key binding `S`). Alternatively, you can call this command with a numeric prefix `N` in order to sort the `N`th column, or click the corresponding column header with the mouse.

You can customise the name, width, contents, and alignment of the columns displayed in `*Magit Repositories*` via the variable `magit-repolist-columns`, which see.  For example, to add a column in the third position indicating uncommitted changes (see comments below), you could do:

```el
(setq magit-repolist-columns
      '(("Name"    25 magit-repolist-column-ident ())
        ("Version" 25 magit-repolist-column-version ())
        ("D"        1 magit-repolist-column-dirty ())
        ("B<U"      3 magit-repolist-column-unpulled-from-upstream
         ((:right-align t)
          (:help-echo "Upstream changes not in branch")))
        ("B>U"      3 magit-repolist-column-unpushed-to-upstream
         ((:right-align t)
          (:help-echo "Local changes not in upstream")))
        ("Path"    99 magit-repolist-column-path ())))
```

You could achieve the same thing without having to redefine the whole list like so:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'magit-repos
  ;; Avoid destructively modifying a list literal.
  (let ((cols (copy-sequence magit-repolist-columns)))
    (push '("D" 1 magit-repolist-column-dirty ())
          (nthcdr 2 cols))
    (setq magit-repolist-columns cols)))
```

Of course, you could also skip having to write this Elisp yourself and just use the customisation interface (`M-x customize-group RET magit-repolist RET`), but where's the fun in that? ;)

#### Issue 2

You can open `magit-status` for each repository listed in `*Magit Repositories*` by typing `M-x magit-repolist-status` (default binding `C-m` or `RET`) on the corresponding line.  Batch operations like pulling are deliberately not implemented in Magit, but are simple enough to write on your own; see https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2971.  You could hack mapping something like `magit-pull-from-pushremote` over all entries in the list, for example.

#### Issue 3

Note that populating the user option `magit-repository-directories` with strings instead of `(DIRECTORY . DEPTH)` cons cells was only supported for backward compatibility, and the obsolete fallback variable `magit-repository-directories-depth` has since been removed.  I recommend you restructure your setting as:

```el
(setq magit-repository-directories
      `(("~/go/src/github.com/cescoferraro" . DEPTH1)
        (,user-emacs-directory              . DEPTH2)))
```

where `DEPTH1` and `DEPTH2` are the respective maximum depths to look for Git repositories, as documented by the variable `magit-repository-directories`.

Comment: To clarify: I am pretty sure that `L` and `U` stand for `Local` and `Upstream`, which may help clarify their meaning. If you find this confuses you, just customise `magit-repolist-columns`.

Comment: See [relevant Magit feature request](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2961)

Comment: You may also be interested in this [useful feature](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2907).

Comment: You are a legend. But my setup is broken, Thats the whole cause of the issues.  Neither C-m nor RET fire `magit-repolist-status`. I using evil and evil-magit.  Is there a magit-repolist-hook I can set this manually? Concerning the issue 3, I figure DEPTH = 1 is ok if I do not use submodules right?

Comment: Could you also point me to a hacked columns setup I could borrow from? Seems like the magit/issues/2907 is exactly what I want!

Comment: (evil-define-key (list 'normal 'insert 'visual 'motion)  magit-repolist-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'magit-repolist-status) solved my issue

Comment: @CESCO If you do not use submodules, then a DEPTH of 0 is sufficient. This just means add the directory itself.

Comment: @CESCO Updated the answer with a custom column example.

Comment: i like the first column approach. Path column in my case is useless. Can I set the columns width?

Comment: @CESCO Yes, just look at the variable's documentation (`C-h v magit-repolist-columns`). The second element of each element of `magit-repolist-columns` represents a column width.